# Entity Framework detect changes before SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a Web API that uses Entity Framework and an Angular SPA. I get an entity and pass it to the SPA, but then I get a DTO back from the SPA into my API. Now what is the best way to check to see if the data has changed by someone else?

One possible scenario is to send the original entity along with the modified entity and do a select by the columns I am modifying. If no rows are returned then the data has changed. This might work, but I wanted to see if there is a better way of detecting changes; especially in the case that the data itself is not in an entity but in a DTO.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Some of our tables have many columns, so we cannot use row version, because we want allow a user to make changes if a previous user changed different columns for the same record. So the other choice of having a where clause would work better, but again if there is a better approach would be appreciated

Comment: I suppose you could include the original values in the DTO, and check to see if they've changed

Comment: But that also raises another question.  What if a user would have changed a column if it was different?  can an unchanged column count as a "change"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow

Comment: If you allow a user to change columns only if the previous user changed different columns, the row you end up with is neither what the first user sent, nor is it what the second user sent.

Comment: Yes, when the second user wants to do an update the where clause of the update would be based on PK and based on the columns it wants to change. So if no user updated the same columns as the second user then the update would work. Otherwise 0 rows will be updated, thus we would know that some other users have updated the same columns